# Dimension of charge pump diode

Tags: diodes, stepper-motor

I am using a L6470H as step motor driver. The data sheet told me to use the following configuration for voltage pumping:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvBu0Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Value of C1 and C2 is not correct). I used a combined diode with 40V breakdown voltage, and 250 mA as forward current as D1 and D2 ([(Datasheet)](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1836110.pdf)), after I assumed that the maximum voltage will be 2*12V. Nevertheless it burned on the first live test. What should be the maximum resistance of the diode? 48V? How can I calculate that?

Update: Apparently the problem was in the Driver, after VBOOT has a direct connection to GND, leading to 12V/20A max going through the diode array.

Comment: 40V/48V are not resistances of a diode. Are you talking about its breakdown voltage? You probably want to look for the diodes amp rating.

Answer (score 1):

The diode you used should be adequate. The BAT64 series come in several pinouts and it is not unheard-of for pin numbers to get mixed up on an SMT part footprint vs. schematic symbol.

Check directly with a multimeter on diode function that the pinout and wiring is what it should be.

Comment: The diode just smoked up, so measuring is out of question. But nevertheless the information about the diode is useful. Which else reasons could the failure have?

Comment: Faulty part(s) including the chip (unlikely) or a short (testing should detect it, perhaps even in your charred prototype).

Comment: You mean that a short circuit induced a too high current on the diode?

Comment: Sure- suppose the VBOOT pin was shorted to the grounded thermal pad under the chip- that would certainly do it.

Comment: It wasn't, the chip itself was faulty.